# JavaScript Accordion Toggle First Element Active

Tags: javascript

Request a quick help. Got this JS for my accordion. This is the complete script now. 
QN: How do I modify the JS to enable my first panel element get active/expanded on page load but toggle (as it already does) on click?

Thanks in advance.

```js
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;
    
    
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].onclick = function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight){
          panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
      }
    }
```

```css
  .panel {overflow:hidden;max-height:0}
```

```html
     <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
    <div class="panel">My Content 1</div>

    <button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
    <div class="panel">My Content 2</div>
```

Hope the script can run now.

Comment: can you able to give it in snippet

Comment: I've added one @KalaiselvanA

Comment: you can trigger `acc[0].click();`  this

Comment: That's brief & perfect, thanks @KalaiselvanA

Comment: sounds good!...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope It'll helpful to you here, I just trigger the click function of first accordion

```js
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    
    var i;
    
    
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].onclick = function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight){
          panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
      }
    }
    acc[0].click();
```

```css
  .panel {overflow:hidden;max-height:0}
```

```html
     <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
    <div class="panel">My Content 1</div>

    <button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
    <div class="panel">My Content 2</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code when you load or created after your accordion menu

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
acc[0].classList.toggle("active");
```

Comment: Apparently the content to show is in the nextElementSibling of each accordion menu. Needs a few more lines. I've added a Snippet.